# Why is OGC error "NoApplicableCode" mapped to HTTP 400?

Tags: error, ogc, http

The "OGC Web Feature Service 2.0 Interface Standard" says that the OGC Error "NoApplicableCode" should be mapped to an HTTP 400 Error with the reason phrase "Internal Server Error" [1]. This is weird, because HTTP 400 is usually "Bad Request", while "Internal Server Error" is used for HTTP 500 [2].

My question: is there a know reason for this combination? Is it possible that this is simply a typo in the specification document?

[1] http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html#411
[2] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

Comment: Status codes are used oddly also in some other places in WFS 2.0, see https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=57387.

Comment: I see no reason why this question should be opinion based or off-topic.